# Setting html form input to session varible

Tags: php, html

I can't put my form input values into session varible

I need to store form inputs into a session variable because I  have to use them in some other pages
When I print the sessin value below the code I get empty array

```
<?php 
session_start();
include('config/dbConnect.php');

if(isset($_POST["email"])){
    $email = $_POST["email"];
    $_SESSION["email"] = $email;

}
if(isset($_POST["password"])){
    $password = $_POST["password"];
    $_SESSION["password"] = $password;
}

print_r($_SESSION);

?>

<!DOCKTYPE html>
<html>

    <?php

    include('templates/header.php');
    ?>
     <section class='container grey-text'>
      <h4 class='center'>Please Log In</h4>
        <form class='white' action = "" method="SESSION">
            <label >Email</label>
            <input type="text" name="email" method = "SESSION">
            <label >Password</label>
            <input type="text" name="password" method = "SESSION">
            <div class ="center">
                <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Log In" class="btn z-depth-0">
            </div> 
        </form>
     </section>

<body> 


</html>
```

Comment: `method="SESSION"` in the `form` tag needs to be `method="POST"`. It needs to be the HTTP method you want to use, and matches what you write in the php (e.g. $_POST). And individual form fields don't have "method" attritibutes at all. Please pay closer attention to the many, many tutorials and documentation pages you can already find online relating to HTML forms and php.